# Why does my button click event handler not do what I expect?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

so I found a blackjack source code on this [forum](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=165092), but I have a problem to make it work. I had made the form myself for the code and I think that is the problem. The game should start when I click the "new button", but nothing happen when I click on it.
Here is the source code:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls, Buttons;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BetCount: TLabel; //not used
    MoneyEdit: TEdit; //not used
    BetEdit: TEdit; //not used
    HitBtn: TButton;
    MoneyCountLbl: TLabel; //not used
    NewBtn: TButton;
    StandBtn: TButton;
    PlayerEdit: TEdit;
    DealerEdit: TEdit;
    MemoDealer: TMemo;
    MemoPlayer: TMemo;
    procedure PickASuit;
    procedure PickACard;
    procedure CardName;
    procedure LookAtHands;
    procedure newDeal;
    procedure DoIt(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public

    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}  
var
suitNum, cardNum, current, total1, total2 : Integer;
suitStr, cardStr : String[8];

procedure TForm1.PickASuit;
begin
suitNum := random(4)+1;
Case suitNum of
1 : suitStr := 'Spades';
2 : suitStr := 'Clubs';
3 : suitStr := 'Diamonds';
4 : suitStr := 'Hearts';
end;
end;



procedure TForm1.CardName;
begin
Case cardNum of
1 : cardStr := 'Ace';
2 : cardStr := 'Two';
3 : cardStr := 'Three';
4 : cardStr := 'Four';
5 : cardStr := 'Five';
6 : cardStr := 'Six';
7 : cardStr := 'Seven';
8 : cardStr := 'Eight';
9 : cardStr := 'Nine';
10 : cardStr := 'Ten';
11 : cardStr := 'Jack';
12 : cardStr := 'Queen';
13 : cardStr := 'King';
end;

Case cardNum of
1 : cardNum := 11;
10..13 : cardNum := 10;
end;

end;

procedure TForm1.PickACard;
begin
cardNum := random(13)+1;
PickASuit; {runs pickasuit procedure}
CardName; {runs cardnume procedure}

Case current of {tells the program what its doing}
  1 : begin
  MemoPlayer.Lines.Add(cardStr + ' of ' + suitStr );
  total1 := total1 + cardNum;
  PlayerEdit.Text := IntToStr(total1);
  end;

  2 : begin
  MemoDealer.Lines.Add(cardStr + ' of ' + suitStr );
  total2 := total2 + cardNum;
  DealerEdit.Text := IntToStr(total2);
  end;

end;
end;

procedure TForm1.LookAtHands;
Begin
If total2 > 21 then ShowMessage('House Busted')
Else if total1 > total2 then ShowMessage('You win')
Else if total1 = total2 then ShowMessage('Draw')
Else ShowMessage('You lose');
newDeal;
End;

procedure TForm1.newDeal;
Begin
MemoDealer.Clear;
MemoPlayer.Clear;
total1 := 0;
total2 := 0;
current := 1;
PickACard;
current := 2;
PickACard;
end;

procedure TForm1.DoIt(Sender: TObject);
begin
current := (Sender as TButton).Tag;
Case current of
1 : Begin
PickACard;
If total1 > 21 then
begin ShowMessage('Busted');
newDeal;
end;
end;

2 : begin While total2 < 17 do PickACard;
LookAtHands;
end;

3 : newDeal;
end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Randomize;
end;
end.
```

I set hit, new, and stand buttons to execute the procedure 'DoIt'

[image]

Do I make a mistake ? I'm just starting to learn delphi, so I hope you guys can understand if I do something "stupid" .

Comment: Your "DoIt" event handler queries the Tag of the buttons. When designing the form did you assign a number to these Tags? If not then the Tag is 0 and nothing will happen in "DoIt" because it expects Tag to be 1, 2, etc.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? If you don't know how to debug then you are asking the wrong question. It is pointless to proceed in your endeavours if you aren't making strenuous efforts to learn debugging skills.

Comment: I wonder how `{$mode objfpc}` compiled, in Delphi. So I assume this was in Lazarus and not in Delphi?

Comment: You also must learn how to indent code. If you don't, you will be endlessly confused and nobody (and I really mean nobody) will ever want to help you because your code is unreadable.

Comment: @wp_1233996 yeah, I didn't know about "tag" before. But after you and Roald van Doorn mentioned about it, I started to google about it and now the program works perfectly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, I don't know how to do it and why I should do it. I'm still learning the basic thing. I will start to learn more about debugging and write my code more "clean" next time. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis sorry, newbie error. You're right, it's on Lazarus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not fill the tag properties of the Buttons on the form. Look in the list of properties of each button for the `Tag` property. The `HitBtn` should have a Tag of 1. There's at least one other button that should have a `Tag` of 2.

Comment: yeah, you absolutely right. After I set the tag for new button to 3, hit button to 1, and stand button to 2, the program works perfectly now. I had no idea about that "tag" before as I'm still learning the simple and basic thing. Well, I learn new thing. Thank you.